arXiv compiler error:
I'm uploading a document to arXiv, but I have this rather cryptic error from the arXiv LaTeX compiler:
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...to Eq. \ref {main-eq:fktD} for $\SI
{100}{s} < t < \SI {1000}{...
l.154 ...D} for $\SI{100}{s} < t < \SI{1000}{s}$.}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

How can I debug this error? It seems that the ... is hiding the real error message
This question is annoyingly similar to my previous question on errors from the arXiv compiler, the root source of which being that the arXiv compiler truncates the error message so I can't see the full message. If anyone has a good way of debugging error messages from arXiv, please let me know.

Don't you get a full log back instead of these sniplets?

Have you tried to compile it on your local computer? Can you copy&paste the error message (if there is any one) from the log file keeping the formatting, which is essential for the semantic of the error message? However, debugging LaTeX errors is more or less always the same: Reduce your document to a minimal working example. This would also allow you to show the code here, so that we can help you solving the problem.

@daleif sadly I not, if I had the full error message, I guess I would be able to solve the problem myself

@cabohah it compiles fine for me locally. I guess I will have to try a MWE yes, but given I have to upload to arXiv every time, it will be tedious, hence asking if anyone has seen this before

Because you should be able to identify the place in your source code, you should be able to reduce the code in a few steps.

the arxiv info at  https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html  says you can get the full log "The information contained in this complete log should be sufficient to identify the problem, "

@DavidCarlisle I think we can both agree that in this case that information is wrong, or are you implying that there is a complete log somewhere else that I have not found?

I assumed the info is right but I didn't want to make a fake arxiv submission to test it

I agree with David. But if the information is really not correct, you could contact the support. This is nothing we could change.

In case someone comes across this in the future, the two errors I had were use of \SI{}{} in a figure caption, and language = {en} in bibliography entries.

But were you able to get the full log?

@Teepeemm sadly not. I used the little clues that were in the error message and deleted lines until it worked. No idea why either of those statements caused the problem
